# Создание общей модели Laravel

Tags: laravel

Можно ли подобное организовать в Laravel? До этого работал с Codigniter и создавал одну общую модель которая отвечала за сохранение, удаление, обновление, в метод просто передавал название таблицы. Здесь же смотрю немного по другому, каждая модель имеет закрытое свойство в котором хранится название таблицы. Попробовал вот такое, подскажите по верному пути иду?

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class General extends Model{

    public static function getAll($table){
        $query = DB::table($table)->get();  
        return $query;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Вам никто не запрещает создать дополнительный класс, который бы работал со всеми моделями одновременно.

Comment: И в свойство table подставлять название таблицы которое пришло параметром в методе?

Comment: только вопрос - зачем? зачем все сбрасывать в кучу, модель это отдельная сущность со своим набором свойств и методов. на вашем месте я бы лучше использовал query builder https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries

Comment: Ну лично мне было удобно использовать на codigniter одну общую модель которая содержала общие методы сохранения выборки и тому подобное.Вот если я захочу создать свой метод выборки с параметрами сортировки,лимита   и тому подобное,это же мне придется в каждой модели создавать такой метод? А так в общей модели был бы метод который принимал в виде параметра название таблицы,тем самым был бы общим для всех моделей

Comment: Ну так и создайте общую модель `General`, а остальные наследуйте от нее, а не от `Model` или `Eloquent`. В метод название таблицы передавать не надо будет, если имя модели будет совпадать с именем таблицы в CamelCase. У вас все отнаследовавшиеся модели будут иметь методы как из General, так и из `Model` или `Eloquent`...

Comment: Чтобы свои фильтры делать не привязываясь к таблице воспользуйтесь `Query Scopes` https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes Вы бы поконкретнее пример привели что сделать хотите в общей модели

Comment: Так и сделаю наверное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Таким путем лучше не идти. Код должен быть разделен и не зависим.

Но если очень хочется, можете написать класс-обертку, который будет работать с той моделью, которая будет передаваться ему. Лучше как Dependency Injection.